# ESLint or Flow - Force references to a variable be prefixed by an existence check

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

Is there a way to force all references to a variable be prefixed by a check for their existence?

We recently added server side rendering for one of our applications and have had a few incidents with people referencing `window` in a server side rendered component, where `window` is not defined.

Is there a way for every time someone references window to have it prefixed by `typeof window !== 'undefined'`?

For instance

```
const isEligible = () =>
   window &&
   window.screen &&
   window.screen.availHeight > 200;
```

should either be an eslint or flow error saying that there should be a check for `typeof window !== 'undefined'` before the first window reference?

Note that I already know about `no-undef` for eslint - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef. This doesn't work, however, because window will be defined for the vast majority of references, its only when its used in the render function of specific components that it should be flagged.

Comment: Hopefully someone can provide a flow-specific answer, but in typescript you would add `window` to a global declaration file and denote it as a union of the object and `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Flow's [built-in libdefs](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/b763a8d35db64e310b9c04579e63d1918f457af7/lib/bom.js#L36) declare `window` as type `any`. You can override that declaration to have type `?any`, forcing a nullness check. You could do this in each of the files where you want these protections, or you could do it project-wide by putting it in a file included in the [`[libs]`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/libs/) section of your `.flowconfig`.

```
declare var window: ?any;

window.foo; // expected error

if (window) {
  window.foo; // no error
}
```

[(try)](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8DuBLAdsA9qgXPAPxSYCeA3AFBUbZ4B0AZjjhfAPQfwgAeADuAAuIYDxgwcMGuibwAFHVyoAlPADeVeGizLmrdl3iYc4ydIC+QA)